# Inboundmails not working in sugarcrm

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, inbound

I configured the Gmail settings for my SugarCRM instance's inbound emails. The Emails do not sync in my CRM instance. Can any one provide help with configuration steps?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some debug steps:

1. Are you able to select the trash folder and get contact with your gmail account?
2. What does it say when you edit the inbound email and press "Test settings"?
3. Did you activate crontab to run on the server? The scheduler "Check Inbound Mail Accounts" are responsible to check the email accounts. What are the latest result of this scheduler?
4. Is the gmail account set up properly with the correct protocols activated (POP or IMAP)?